# What is it called when a WiFi chip advertises its own SSID so users can connect

Tags: radio, wifi, linux, network

I am not sure which stack should I post this, but here is my question:

when you buys these WiFi-enabled gadgets, when they turn on they advertise a SSID where you can connect to it and enter your homes network detail in them.

What is this mode called? Access Point? Hot spot? Is this possible to be done on a raspberry pi zero?

Comment: Soft Access Point or Access Point mode

Comment: Yes, you can set up a Raspberry Pi as an access point, and in fact there are tutorials on how to do it.